# How can I have a unique instance of a lambda on the heap that I share across various consumers?

Tags: lambda, rust

I do not seem to be able to circumvent the fact that running the lambda, moves it out of the shared reference.

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

fn run_my_fn(my_fn: Rc<impl FnOnce() -> u32>) -> u32 {
    (*my_fn)(); // cannot move out of an `Rc`
    (my_fn.as_ref())() // cannot move out of a shared reference
}

fn main() {
    let my_fn = Rc::new(|| { 123 as u32 });    
    let _res = run_my_fn(my_fn.clone()); 
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=91358a18b197eb936aa6a24efeca1b1e)

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of an `Rc`
 --> src/main.rs:4:5
  |
4 |     (*my_fn)();
  |     ^^^^^^^^ move occurs because value has type `impl FnOnce() -> u32`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error[E0507]: cannot move out of a shared reference
 --> src/main.rs:5:5
  |
5 |     (my_fn.as_ref())() 
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because value has type `impl FnOnce() -> u32`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Comment: @justinas Oh yes. How stupid, changing to Fn works... The compiler message is misleading though (for once). Please answer so I can award it to you

Comment: I voted to close as duplicate so I do not think I should answer. The compiler message is indeed less than ideal, but the thing that tries to "move out of a shared reference" is [call_once](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html#tymethod.call_once) of `FnOnce` that takes `self` by value (i.e. consumes the closure).